# How can I change the marker style for different data types while using pandas for a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a csv file with data for 100 GB places with columns for their name, population, type (town or city), latitude and longitude. I have plotted them on a map of longitude against latitude with the marker sizes proportional to population and colour dependent on nation. I am struggling to find a way to change the marker style. Ideally I would like to have ^ for towns and v for cities. Here is my code so far.

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

# import data file
# select data columns needed
data = pd.read_csv('GBplaces.csv', sep = ',', usecols = (0,1,2,3,4))
# name data columns
data.columns = ('Place','Type','Population','Latitude','Longitude')#



# make markers for towns and cities from different nations different colours
# Scotland in blue
data.loc[(data['Place'] == 'Aberdeen') | (data['Place'] == 'Dundee') | 
(data['Place'] == 'Glasgow') 
| (data['Place'] == 'Edinburgh'),'Colour'] = 'b'

# Wales in black
data.loc[(data['Place'] == 'Swansea') | (data['Place'] == 'Cardiff') | 
(data['Place'] == 'Newport'),'Colour'] = 'black'

# England in red
data.loc[(data['Place'] != 'Aberdeen') & (data['Place'] != 'Dundee') 
& (data['Place'] != 'Glasgow') & (data['Place'] != 'Edinburgh') 
& (data['Place'] != 'Swansea') & (data['Place'] != 'Cardiff') & 
(data['Place'] != 'Newport'),'Colour'] = 'r'

# legend created for colours for each nation
red_marker = mpatches.Patch(color='r',label='England')
blue_marker = mpatches.Patch(color='b', label='Scotland')
black_marker = mpatches.Patch(color='black', label='Wales')
legend = plt.legend(handles=[red_marker, blue_marker, black_marker])

# colour added to background
ax = plt.gca()
ax.patch.set_facecolor('#CCFFFF')

# make point size proportional to population
area = data['Population']/100000

plt.scatter(data['Longitude'], data['Latitude'], c = data['Colour'], s = 
area, )
```

So far I have tried to the marker style the same way I changed the colour however this results in an empty chart. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First some dummy data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'Place': ['Scotland', 'Scotland', 'England', 'England', 'Wales', 'Wales'], 
    'x': [100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50], 
    'y': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
})
```

Group by `Place` and make a list of `markers` and then loop through it. In your case `Place` would be city or town.

```
from itertools import cycle

ax = plt.gca()
ax.patch.set_facecolor('#FFFFFF')

places = df.groupby('Place')

markers = ['o', '1', ',']

legend_labels = []

for (name, place), marker in zip(places, cycle(markers)):

    ax.scatter(place.x, place.y, marker=marker)

    legend_labels.append(name)

ax.legend(labels=legend_labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]